# tengo problema para imprimir un reporte

Tags: java, ireport

Buenas tengo un sistemas donde llevo el control de soporte pero quiero realizar un reporte que me traiga los soporte pendiente por rango de fecha el reporte esta hecho en ireport y el programa en java
este es el código que estoy usando para manda los parámetros al reporte hecho en ireport si tengo un error en el codigo no lo veo alguien me puede ayudar

```
public static ResultSet ImpInfServPendxRang(String FDesde, String FHasta){
    conectar cc = new conectar ();
    Connection cn = cc.conexion();
    try{
        JasperReport reporte = null;
        String path = "S:\\src\\Reportes\\ImpInfServPendxRang.jasper";
        
        Map parametro = new HashMap();
        parametro.put("f_desde", FDesde);
        parametro.put("f_hasta", FHasta);
        
        reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path);
        JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametro, cn);
        //Visializacion del Reporte
        JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jprint, false);
        view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        view.setVisible(true);
    }catch(JRException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hola. No se entiende cuál es el problema o error. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para clarificar tu problema.